# Is there a way to select the last div element with adjacent non-div element siblings with CSS only?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

[Consider my codepen experiment](https://codepen.io/ckim44/pen/MWadBpz)

I thought that the :last-child and similar pseudo selectors only target the same sibling element. In my experiment this would be a div element. But in my codepen it seems that if there is ANY sibling that comes after the last div element, then the last div element is no longer a last-child.

Is there a way to select the last div element with adjacent non-div element siblings with CSS only?

Right now, it seems my only conclusion is to structure my HTML differently so that the last div is the last element in it's parent. I'm hoping someone has a different answer!

```css
.container {
  background-color: green;
}

.row {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.row:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 8rem;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.row .col-1-of-2 {
  float: left;
  background-color: orangered;
  color: #fff;
  width: calc((100% - 6rem)/2);
}

.row .col-1-of-2:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 6rem;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1-of-2">Col 1 of 2</div>
    <div class="col-1-of-2">Col 1 of 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1-of-2">Col 1 of 2</div>
    <div class="col-1-of-2">Col 1 of 2</div>
  </div>
  <h1>Test</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can do this with [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type)**, which represents the last element of its type among a group of sibling elements.

So your final code should be something like this:

```css
.container {
  background-color: green;
}

.row {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.row:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-bottom: 8rem;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.row .col-1-of-2 {
  float: left;
  background-color: orangered;
  color: #fff;
  width: calc((100% - 6rem)/2);
}

.row .col-1-of-2:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 6rem;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class- "container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1-of-2">Col 1 of 2</div>
    <div class="col-1-of-2">Col 1 of 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1-of-2">Col 1 of 2</div>
    <div class="col-1-of-2">Col 1 of 2</div>
  </div>
  <h1>Test</h1>
</div>
```